# Problemas com buffer pool de memória doMysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, memória, amazon-aws

Olá, tenho uma maquina `EC2` na `AWS radando` ubuntu server. Acontece que o `MySql` parou de funcionar e não volta mais. O `log` de erro apresenta o seguinte:

> ```
> 160919 21:20:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
> InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 160919 21:20:21 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
> 160919 21:20:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
> 160919 21:20:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 160919 21:20:21 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
> 160919 21:20:21 [ERROR] Aborting
> ```

Já tentei setar o valor de:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64
```

porém nada adiantou. Alguém pode me dar um help?

Comment: O erro diz que o MySQL tentou alocar memória e o sistema operacional não deixou. Talvez você esteja tentando usar mais memória do que tem disponível. Já falou com o próprio suporte da Amazon?

Comment: Ver também: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999800

Comment: Erro 12 é "out of memory"! Pelo entendi do log ele está tentando alocar um buffer de 128Mb e não está conseguindo. O valor é meio baixo para dar esse tipo de erro. Qual o resultado do comando "free" nessa mesma máquina?